# Applying an output limit to an equation

Tags: limits

Is it possible to create an equation such that it’s value is capped at some maximum which isn’t asymptotic?

For example: when I ask Siri or Alexa or Hey Google to “increase the volume x%”, for values less than or equal to 50%, these assistants appear to add x% of the current volume to the current volume.  E.g. if the volume is at 45% of the maximum volume already and I ask for the volume to increase by 100%, the volume is set by the assistant to 90% of the maximum volume.

My equation to describe this is PV+PV*R% (where PV = present volume and R = Request).  But what when the volume is over 50% of the maximum volume already?  The volume can not be set to over 100% so the assistant just sets the volume to its maximum setting of 100%.

In all likelihood there is a conditional statement in the assistants program to deal with this but should there be a way to do this mathematically without the calculus so that the output can never exceed a value (such as 100% in my example) or am I trying to square the circle?

Comment: I created this example to illustrate the concept not as a concrete problem.

Comment: In mathematics, there is a two-variable function called $\max(x,y)$ that returns the maximum of two values. So what you'd have is simply $\max(1, V_p(1+R))$ with $V_p$ present volume and $R$ rate of increase, all expressed in decimal points (so 20% is written as 0.2). This is what the algorithms do.

Comment: "Is it possible to create an equation such that it’s value..." stop right there; equations don't have values. It looks like you want a *function*, presumably of a single real variable, that attains a maximum, rather than approaching a maximum asymptotically. But of course there are as many of these as you like, e.g., $f(x)=1-x^2$ achieves its maximum value of $1$ at $x=0$, no asymptotics involved. Same for $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano so, for a present volume of 80% where the request is to increase the volume by 100%: max(1, 0.8(1+1)) = max(1, 0.8(2)) = max(1, 1.6)) = 1.6?  This does not appear to give the desired result of outputting 1 or less.